# Swift 2 Array Contains object?

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

Why isn't this working? I can use array.contains() on a String but it doesn't work for an Object.

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C"]

array.contains("A") // True

class Dog {
    var age = 1
}

var dogs = [Dog(), Dog(), Dog()]
var sparky = Dog()
dogs.contains(sparky) // Error Cannot convert value of type 'Dog' to expected argument type '@noescape (Dog) throws -> Bool
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `Dog` needs to implement `Equatable`.

```
class Dog: Equatable {

   var age = 1

}

func == (lhs: Dog, rhs: Dog) -> Bool {
      return lhs.age == rhs.age
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To really explain what's happening there, first we have to understand there are two `contains` methods on `Array` (or better said, on [SequenceType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_8containsuRq_S__Fq_FzFzqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSbSb)).

```
func contains(_ element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

with constraints

```
Generator.Element : Equatable
```

and

```
func contains(@noescape _ predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

The first one basically searches for a given element in the array using `==`. The second one uses a closure that returns a `Bool` to search for elements.

The first method cannot be used because `Dog` doesn't adopt `Equatable`. The compiler tries to use the second method but that one has a closure as the parameter, hence the error you are seeing.

Solution: implement `Equatable` for `Dog`.

If you are looking for object reference comparison, you can use a simple closure:

```
let result = dogs.contains({ $0 === sparky })
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It's not possible to search for the Object reference?

Comment: @user752543 It is, if you use a closure. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Swift

If you are not using object then you can user this code for contains.

```
let elements = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

if elements.contains(50) {

    print("true")

}
```

If you are using NSObject Class in swift. This variables is according to my requirement. you can modify for your requirement.

```
var cliectScreenList = [ATModelLeadInfo]()
var cliectScreenSelectedObject: ATModelLeadInfo!
```

This is for a same data type.

```
{ $0.user_id == cliectScreenSelectedObject.user_id }
```

If you want to AnyObject type.

```
{ "\($0.user_id)" == "\(cliectScreenSelectedObject.user_id)" }
```

Full condition

```
if cliectScreenSelected.contains( { $0.user_id == cliectScreenSelectedObject.user_id } ) == false {

cliectScreenSelected.append(cliectScreenSelectedObject)

print("Object Added")

} else {

print("Object already exists")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't relevant for the OP's question, but might be helpful to others who are confronted with the Swift error message

> Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type '(*whatever*)'

But first a quick quiz: Can you spot the problem here?

```
internal class FrameworkAdminConnections {

   private var _localConnectionKeys = [Int]()

   ... other code omitted

   public func isLocalConnection(_ connectionKey : Int) {
      return _localConnectionKeys.contains(connectionKey)
   }
}
```

Swift kept telling me I couldn't invoke contains() with an argument list of type (Int), which was a very unhelpful error message, and I don't dare admit how long it took me to finally figure it out.

**The real problem was that Swift's inference engine couldn't figure out what the result of the contains() method should be** - because I'd stupidly not specified "-> Bool" on the isLocalConnection() method signature!